# Android: VideoView or something else?

Tags: android, components, multimedia

I try to make an android application which displays multimedia files.
Multimedia in this case means pictures (eg. jpeg) and movies (eg. mp4).
I figured out there is such component like VideoView. Doc says they can show most of popular formats which is enough for me.
BUT
1. Is there any better compotnent/way to do this? Maybe better solution is to use two components (one for pictures and one for movies) and operate on they visibilities?
2. How to force VideoView to take only part of the screen of my smartphone? VideoView on LinearLayout always tend to take whole space on this layout and pushes out of the screen other layouts (i need to put on the screen movie and some text below). Can i force VideoView to change its size in layout xml?

Comment: I have the same concept where I compare the file extension and depending if it's a image or video , I show it in ImageView or VideoView.

Comment: Thx for replay. I tend to make as compact and easy class as possible. But of course first of all this code shoud be efficient and because of this i have some doubds: i know usually generalization isn't efficient. How you change (if you do it) size of VideoView?

Comment: Create a custom VideoView class and override onMeasure

Comment: Ok, I have class MultimediaContainer with overriden method onMeasure(). But should i add it to xml layout as an MultimediaContainer or VideoView or what? How to make from this class component available in eclipse builder? -- OK, eclipse somehow figured out that i added this as a component and refreshed component list.